# Make request as a date

Tags: php, laravel

I have a column date & from request `date` there are some possibilities coming from the user

- date might come as empty
- date might come as a month and year & I have to make it a full date! like `20204/` => `2020-04-01`
- date might come as normal date `2020-04-01`
- date might come as `1/4/2020` I need to convert it to a real date like `2020-04-01`

I handle the first two but I do not know how to handle the third one or check if it is the full date!

my code:

```
$newDate = null; // 1

$ex = $request->expired_date;

if(DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $myString) !== false){

    $newDate = $ex; // 2

}else {

    $removeSpace = str_replace(' ', '', $ex);

    list($month, $year) = explode('/', $removeSpace);

    $newDate = vsprintf('%s-%s-%s', [$year, $month, '1']); // 3

}
```

I just have 4 one left how can convert the date `1/4/2020` to `2020-04-01` ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Why not ensure that all incoming data is properly formatted? For example, does `2020-04-01` always reference the first of April, or the fourth of January?

Comment: @NicoHaase No, there is no validation because it comes from an excel file! and not always `April`

Answer (score 0):

you can use [strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function in php

```
$date="1/4/2020";
$new_date=date("Y-m-d",strtotime($date));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use DateTime. First you pass the Date ('1/4/2020') to the DateTime constructor. Then you can use the DateTime function format. Give the function the wanted date format ('Y-m-d').

```
$dt = new DateTime('1/4/2020');
$fdt = $dt->format('Y-m-d');
// output: 2020-01-04
```

**Note:** But @NicoHaase is right. Why don't you validate the correct format already in the frontend?